# Звездочки в input type="text"

Tags: php, javascript, input

Добрый день, как сделать, чтобы в поле input type="text" (не password, именно text) введённые символы заменялись на звездочки, но потом передавать введенное значение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<input type=text style="-webkit-text-security: disc;">
```

Comment: А для Firefox и IE?

Comment: спасибо! Работает, а можно сделать кроссбраузерно?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = password;
password = '';
input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if(input.value.length > password.length){
    password += input.value[input.value.length-1];
  }else{
    password = password.substr(0,input.value.length);
  }
  input.value = '*'.repeat(password.length);
  console.log(password);
});
```

```html
<input id="password" />
```

Comment: Правда, не работает если посередине пароля выделить один или несколько символов и заменить. Но кто так делает при вводе пароля)

Comment: слишком быстро обрабатывается или что-то еще идет не так, при быстром вводе пропускает символы